# How do I manage the feed, sidebar and widgets at the middle of the page?

Tags: reactjs, image

[how the clone looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohpj.png)
So im working on a twitter clone and I can't put the feed and widgets at the middle of the screen. It's below the sidebar option. How do I readjust to put them side by side?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, find good hints on how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What have you tried so far? Please share some code!

Answer (score 0):

In the main App.css file
set

```
.app{
display:flex;
}
```

Comment: hey I did that made and it made no difference.

Comment: .app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 10px; #for the app

Comment: is it something with the sidebar? should i share that too?

Comment: .sidebar__twitterIcon {
  color: var(--twitter-color);
  font-size: 30px !important;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar__tweet {
  background-color: var(--twitter-color) !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  text-transform: inherit !important;
  border-radius: 30px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

Comment: where is your main .sidebar

Comment: .sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid var(--twitter-background);
  flex: 0.3;
  /* min-width: 250px; */
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}